# Concentration inequalities for stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request

I understand this is a rather vague question, but I am curious if there exist any generalization of, e.g. Hoeffding's inequality or Chernoff's inequality to the case of stochastic processes? I am in particular interested in upper bounding the following term
$$P(\sup_{t\in T}\vert X(t)-EX(t) \vert \ge c)$$
where $t$ is a continuous (or discrete, if necessary) parameter where $T \subset \mathbb{R}$, $EX(t)$ is the expectation of the random variable $X(t)$, and $X$ and $T$ can be arbitrarily nice, for example, perhaps for Gaussian processes and $T$ compact we can say something about the above term?

Comment: There are plenty of results about suprema of stochastic processes. You can refer e.g. to Roman Vershynin's [book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html), the [book](https://www.amazon.com/Concentration-Inequalities-Nonasymptotic-Theory-Independence/dp/0199535256) by Boucheron, Lugosi & Massart or the [monograph](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~merlet/articles/probas_massart_stf03.pdf) by Massart.

Comment: @VHarisop thanks for the recommendations. A lot of results I see provide bounds for $E \sup_{t\in T} X(t)$ or $P(\sup_{t \in T} |X(t) - X(t_0)| \ge c)$, but not on the tail bound I want, which is basically a tail bound for the supremum of absolute value of a zero mean process. I know Markov's inequality could be useful in the expectation bounds, but are there readily available/better results in the works you mention?

Comment: You can always define $Z(t) := X(t) - \mathbb{E} X(t)$ to be a centered random process and carry on from there.

Comment: @VHarisop yes I know this is true. The issues I have is that for the results I see, e.g. a bound on $P(\sup_{t\in T}|Z(t) - Z(t_0)|\ge c)$, this bound is not immediately usable because I'm interested in bounding $P(\sup_{t\in T}|Z(t)| \ge 0) = P(\sup_{t\in T}|Z(t) - 0| \ge 0)$, and I don't think we can take $Z(t_0)$ equal to $0$ in those results?

Comment: In that case, can you give more information about your setting? You said that $T$ can be arbitrarily nice (e.g. symmetric, star-shaped, etc), so in the case of Gaussian processes you would get bounds on $\sup_{t \in T} |Z(t)|$.

Comment: @VHarisop could you elaborate a little on why in the case of Gaussian process I can simplify $\sup_{t\in T}|Z(t) - Z(t_0)|$ to $\sup_{t\in T}|Z(t)|$ on a "nice" T, or point me to a reference? I am only starting to look for results like this, and I think any result right now could be useful! Also I think you can see that I'm a starter in probability theory, so I'm also using this opportunity to accumulate knowledge. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us also assume $X$ is separable (e.g. continuous). Then $\sup_{t\in T} |X_t| = \sup_{n\ge 1} |X_{t_n}|$, in other words, it is enough to look at sequences.

A useful fact:

> **Theorem (Fernique-Landau-Marcus-Shepp)** Let $(Y_n,n\ge1)$ be a Gaussian sequence, and $Y^* = \sup_{n\ge 1} |Y_n|$. If  $\mathbb P(Y^*<\infty)>0$, then $\mathbb P(Y^*<\infty)=1$, moreover, for any  $c<(2\sigma^2)^{-1}$, where $\sigma^2:=\sup_{n\ge 1} \operatorname{var}(Y_n)$, 
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}[e^{c(Y^*)^2}]<\infty. \tag{1}
> $$

It follows from $(1)$ that 
$$
\limsup_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \log \mathbb P(Y^* \ge x) \le -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}.
$$

Since, clearly, for any $x>0$,
$$
\mathbb P(Y^* \ge x)\ge \mathbb P(\sigma|Z|\ge x), 
$$
where $Z$ is standard Gaussian, it follows that 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \log \mathbb P(Y^* \ge x) = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}.
$$

Going back to $X$, in view of separability, 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \log \mathbb P\left(\sup_{t\in T} |X_t| \ge x\right) = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\tag{2}
$$
with $\sigma^2 = \sup_{t\in T} \operatorname{var}(X_t)$ provided that $X$ is separable and bounded. (Note that this is stated in [Marcus-Shepp](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s6_v2_article-26.pdf) , but it seems that the authors forgot to explain this.)

The statement $(2)$ is "large-deviation" type and asymptotic, i.e. you don't have a precise bound for the probability. In order to get one, you need to impose some assumptions on the mean (which can be assumed zero for your question) and covariance of $X$. There are many works by Marcus, Pisier, Fernique, Talagrand, and others; you can start by looking in Google Scholar which articles cite Marcus-Shepp.